# usage of emphasis do in No sooner structure

Tags: emphasis

> No dooner did we do leave home than the rain started.

I wanted to know whether I can use 'do' as emphasis
in this sentence.

Comment: _"No dooner did we do left home than the rain started"_ has no meaning in English, even if the splelling is corrected. You should consider looking closely at what you have written before posting your questions.

Comment: You have already used the "do" in "No sooner **did** we leave home".